# How to use a string variable with LocalizedStringKey

Tags: swiftui, localizedstringkey

I'm stuck when trying to use a variable to define a LocalizedStringKey. For example, in the simplified code below, Option 1 returns the translated value from my localizable.strings file but I'm trying to get Option 2 to work. The returned error is "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time....".

````
var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, to: 2, by: 1)), id: \.self) { index_v in
            let sPartList: [String] = ["ST", "MT", "LT"]
            let test: LocalizedStringKey = "ST"  // Option 1 works
            // let test: LocalizedStringKey = sPartList[0]  //Option 2 doesnt work
            
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                Text("Hello")
                Text(test)
              }
         }
}```
````

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all consider that `from: 0, to: 2` returns the numbers 0 and 1, if you want 0, 1 and 2 you have to use `through`

To make the second option work just create an `LocalizedStringKey` explicitly and use the index variable rather than a fixed literal.

```
ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, through: 2, by: 1)), id: \.self) { index in
   let test = LocalizedStringKey(sPartList[index])
   ...
```

Annotate types only if the compiler cannot infer them.

Comment: Thx that worked. The annotation of the type was messing up.